# Cook–Levin theorem and reduction as injective function

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, reductions

I saw that the injectivity "derives directly from the theorem", but i can't see how it's happen, any explanation?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly do they mean, but isn't it true that the resulting circuit can only be constructed from a unique nondeterministic TM?

Comment: @Dmitry Thank you, I think it's not about TM, maybe the answer to this question is: to each CNF can be added one or more clauses that make it possible map each unique domain to unique codomain. but I'm not sure

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to provide more context and background?  I'm not sure what your question is asking, and I don't know where you read that quote or the context or what it is referring to, so it's hard to know how to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, but let me hazard a guess. Let $L$ be an NP language. According to the Cook–Levin theorem, there is a polynomial time reduction $\phi_L$ from $L$ to SAT, that is, $\phi_L$ is a polynomial time function that satisfies $x \in L$ iff $\phi_L(x) \in \mathrm{SAT}$. You are asking why $\phi_L$ is injective.

Roughly speaking, $\phi_L(x)$ constructs a formula which describes the operation of a nondeterministic Turing machine for $L$ executing on $x$. The input $x$ is hardcoded in this description, and in particular, we can extract $x$ from $\phi_L(x)$. This implies that $\phi_L$ is injective.